# Android Kotlin smart operator overloading

Tags: android, kotlin, operator-overloading, android-resources

What if overload some `Kotlin` operator and use it like this:

```
// Inits somewhere before usage.
val someStrFromServer: String? 
lateinit var myFieldText: TextView

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    myFieldText.text = someStrFromServer / R.string.app_none
}
```

Operator overloading:

```
operator fun String?.div(resId: Int): String {
    return if (this.isNullOrBlank()) {
        context.getString(resId)
    } else {
        this
    }
}
```

Output if **`someStrFromServer`** null:

```
D/DEBUG: None
```

Output if **`someStrFromServer`** not null:

```
D/DEBUG: someStrFromServer
```

Does anyone know, if in `Kotlin` exists a more efficient and short way to handle this? Perhaps, even more, *global*, like `extension function`.

Comment: I'd suggest using a regular extension function for this with an appropriate name instead of an operator, as this has nothing to do with division.

Comment: @zsmb13 Yeah! Thanks! It is just an idea, nothing more. Especially I do not recommend to use that in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, but it's not very intuitive because the `div` is normally used in mathematical calculations only. I'd recommend to use something like

```
someStrFromServer.takeUnless { it.isNullOrBlank()} ?: context.getString(resId)
```

Or simplified via extension

```
fun String?.fallback(resId: Int) = takeUnless { it.isNullOrBlank()} ?: context.getString(resId)
```

used like this:

```
myFieldText.text = someStrFromServer.fallback(R.string.app_none)
```

Comment: Agree with _" it's not very intuitive because the div is normally used in mathematical calculations only "_ !

Comment: Maybe create kind of  `as`, `is`, etc. I mean `infix functions`?

Comment: yeah you could make that shown extension an infix function if you like this

Comment: I would use `someStrFromServer ?: context.getString(R.string.app_none)`

Comment: @shkschneider Yeah, good one, but I am lazy) I used to write like in your example. I want to write as few as possible.

Comment: + you don't only want to test for `null` but also empty string `""` which the elvis operator does not catch